Telegram bot with Telethon and TimeoutError
I made a simple Telegram bot with Telethon:
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from config import *
client = TelegramClient('bot_session',api_id= api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern= r'/start'))
async def start(event):
    await client.send_message(entity=event.chat_id,message='Hi')



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

But after running I have an error and I don't know why?
I even used VPS or VPN and PROXY.
Please advise someone who has done this.
Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Attempt 2 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Attempt 3 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Attempt 4 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Attempt 5 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Attempt 6 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\MyPython\TelegramBot\TelegramBot-telethon.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 128, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 135, in _start
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 547, in connect
    if not await self._sender.connect(self._connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 134, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 260, in _connect
    raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

